# Perl - Odd number of elements in hash assignment in Constructor

Tags: perl, hash, constructor

I have some problems calling a constructor with a hash.
I get the error:

"Odd number of elements in hash assignment at Sumcheck.pm line 4".
Sumcheck.pm looks like this:

```
package Sumcheck;

sub new {
    my ($debug, $debug_matches,%checkHash) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    $self->{DEBUG} = $debug;
    $self->{DEBUG_MATCHES} = $debug_matches;
    $self->{CHECKRESULT_OK} = "COMPLIANT"; 
    $self->{CHECKRESULT_ERROR} = "NONCOMPLIANT"; 
    $self->{checkHash} = %checkHash;
    #print %checkHash;

    bless($self);
    return $self;
}
1;
```

And i call it like this(just a random hash):

```
use Sumcheck;
$debug = 0;
$debug_matches = 1;

%checkHash = (  'The Shining'       => 'Kubrick',
                'Ten Commandments'  => 'DeMille',
                'Goonies'           => 'Donner',);

$sumCheck = Sumcheck->new($debug, $debug_matches, %checkHash);
```

Why do i get this error? How it is solved?

Thx :)

Comment: Do you mean to store a *reference* to `%checkHash` in the object?  `$self->{checkHash} = %checkHash` [sic] likely doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first implicit argument to a method called like this:

```
MyPackage->someMethod()
```

is the name of the package.  Eg:

```
package MyPackage;

sub someMethod {
    print shift;
```

will yield **MyPackage**.

The idea WRT to constructors is:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;  # now your $debug would be $_[0], so:
    my $self = { @_ };  # <- replace this with your own details
    bless $self, $class;
}
```

You don't have to do exactly that, but do you see now why your hash has an odd number of elements?  In `Sumcheck::new`, `$debug` is not what you think it is (check).  Remember, a hash is passed literally as a list like this:

```
name, value, name, value
```

So, "Sumcheck" (the package name) gets placed in `$debug`, 0 gets placed into `$debug_matches` then the first element of the hash is 1, leading to this:

```
1 => `The Shining`
'Kubrick' => 'Ten Commandments',
'DeMille' => 'Goonies',
'Donner'  =>  # uneven number of elements error
```

FYI, the first implicit argument to an object method called this way (the second line):

```
my $obj = Sumcheck->new(..,.);
$obj->someMethod();
```

Will be $obj, aka. the `$self` in the method:

```
sub someMethod {
    my $self = shift
```

which is the blessed hash returned by the constructor, `new()`.

Comment: hmm yes i see - thx for the good explanation. I also tested it - with the same results :). But i still cant see how you would solve this.

Comment: The first thing you do in a package sub is shift off the first implicit argument.  For instance methods, that's `$self`.  For a constructor, you treat it as the name of the class (since it was called via `Sumcheck->new()`, not `$obj->new()`), which you should use as the second argument to `bless`.  Have a look at my example `new()`.  You just want to replace the `$self = { @_ }` line with whatever you want -- probably, `my ($debug, $debug_matches,%checkHash) = @_;` and proceed from there.

Comment: thx tried that - it works now :) thx a lot to both goldilocks & Nikhil Jain!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, always *use* `use strict` and `use warnings` in you program.

The program is not working as you expected, becuase whenever you make a object of the class then first parameter is always the instance of the class, so write it like this way:

```
package Sumcheck;
use strict;
use warnings;

   sub new {
   # $checkhash variable holds the reference of the hash.
   my ($class, $debug, $debug_matches,$checkHash) = @_; #$class would hold the instance
   my $self = {};
   $self->{DEBUG} = $debug;
   $self->{DEBUG_MATCHES} = $debug_matches;
   $self->{CHECKRESULT_OK} = "COMPLIANT";
   $self->{CHECKRESULT_ERROR} = "NONCOMPLIANT";
   $self->{checkHash} = %{$checkHash};
   #print %checkHash;
   bless($self);
   return $self;
   }
   my %test = ( abc => "30"); # for testing
   # pass hash as reference
   my $sumcheck = Sumcheck->new('test', 'test20', \%test ); 
   print"$sumcheck->{DEBUG}"; # for testing
   1;
```

Above code will solve your problem.

Comment: You changed the argument processing from `my (..., %h) = @_` to `my (..., $h) = @_`, which will give the OP a new problem (ignored arguments) in place of the old problem (improper hash assignment).

Comment: @pilcrow: I am suggesting the OP to pass the hash refenence instead of hash like `my $sumcheck = Sumcheck->new('test', 'test20', \%test );`, it will work fine, It would not give any problem like improper hash assignment.

Comment: Yes, I know, but you didn't explain that you were changing the method's call parameters and thus breaking the OP's invocation.  :)

Comment: Added one comment in the code, `# $checkhash variable holds the reference of the hash.`, hope, now it would not breaking the OP's invocation and OP could understand the code.

Comment: Isn't it better to use the two-argument version of `bless` (`bless $self,$class;`) which would allow the class to be inherited.

Comment: @dgw: Ofcourse, it would be better to use two argument version of bless, I didnt do it becuase my intension was, OP first understand what is going wrong in his program.Thereafter would be nice to tell this thing.